# How to do elasticsearch aggregation on property names that contain space

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to run an aggregation on a property name contains space in it.
So this is the query body of the search

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "categoryId": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "title.list": "iphone"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "results": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category.l3.id",
            "size": 4
          },
          "aggs": {
            "categoryName": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "category.l3.id.keyword",
                "size": 1
              }
            }
            "Operating_System": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "detail.attribute.Operating System.raw",
                "size": 9
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the property name "Operating System" has a space. I tried running like this

```
"field": "detail.attribute['Operating System'].raw"
```

It still doesn't work. How do i fix this?
This is the mapping

```
 "detail": {
    "properties": {        
        "attribute": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {               
                "Operating System": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example document from your index?

Comment: @sramalingam24 Here is a part of the document<br>
`"_source": {
    "detail": {
        "attribute": {
            "Operating System": [
                "Windows 7 Home Premium",
                2
            ]
        }
        "attList": [
            "Operating System"
        ]
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Apparently space in property name is legal.

```
"Operating_System": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "detail.attribute.Operating System.raw",
                "size": 9
              }
            }
```

I dont know how it didnt worked before, maybe i missed something but this query will return a response

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "\" behind the space for this to work.
try doing it this way

```
"detail": {
    "properties": {        
        "attribute": {
            "dynamic": "true",
            "properties": {               
                "Operating\ System": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```